# Passing 2 php variables using javascript/JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, variables

I have a Jquery code that listens for the selection from a user and displays the information that the user needs.  The user selects a "folder" and then the content appears after they selected.

There are 2 pages.  The first page has the jquery code and the selection box and the div that the information is the be displayed in.  Our problem is I got the folder name to pass but I need to pass along the $username as well so that it knows what folders to look up.

This is the first page.  It's the selection box and also jquery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#theselect").change(function() {
var option = $(this).val();
        $.get("selectfolders.php", {select:option},function(data){
            $("#theresult").html(data).hide().fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });
});
</script>




echo "
<select name='thename' id='thename' style='visibility:hidden;' >
<option value='$username'>$username</option>
</select>";
?>
<select name="theselect" id="theselect">
<option value="">Select</option>
<?
$thelistquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM folders WHERE username='$username'");
while ($lrows = mysql_fetch_array($thelistquery)) {
$id = $lrows['ID'];
$username = $lrows['username'];
$foldername = $lrows['foldername'];
$newfoldername = mysql_real_escape_string($foldername);

echo "<option value='$newfoldername'>$newfoldername</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

This is the second page.  It generates the list of folders and displays the folder the user selects on the first page:

```
$thelistquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM folders WHERE username='$username'");
while ($lrows = mysql_fetch_array($thelistquery)) {
$id = $lrows['ID'];
$username = $lrows['username'];
$foldername = $lrows['foldername'];
$newfoldername = mysql_real_escape_string($foldername);

if($_GET['select'] == '$newfoldername') {
echo "This is the $newfoldername folder.";
}
}
```

We need to add code the the javascript to take the $username from the first page and pass it to the second page so it knows whose folders to look up.  Any help?

Comment: @dikirill: Why didn't you make that an answer?

Comment: I don't get, how you get from first page to second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar problem and this is how i fixed it:

```
 $("#theselect").change(function() {
    var option = $(this).val();
    var selectedUser = $("#thename").val();
    $.get("selectfolders.php", {select:option,username:selectedUser},function(data){
        $("#theresult").html(data).hide().fadeIn(1000);
    });
 });
```

For this to work make sure that the  username is selected at the moment adding the "selected" HTML attribute to the option.
However I think it will be easier if you just use a hidden  block:

```
<input type="hidden" value="$username" name="username" id="username" >
```

Comment: if i could up it i would.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get("selectfolders.php", {select:option, username:username},function(data){});
```

Comment: Do I just set the $username as an input type=hidden and it'll send it?

Comment: You can do it like this, or {select:option, username:'<?=$username?>'}

Comment: One more questions.  I have this to call the folder name on the second page:

'$_GET['select'];'

What would be the one to get the username?  '$_GET['username']' ?

Comment: Still not working.  Here's what I have in the script:

`$.get("selectfolders.php", {select:option, username:'<?=$username?>'},function(data){});`

Here's what I have on the second page to call the info:

`$username = $_GET['username'];`

Comment: Looks fine. But, do you have '$username' variable set on first page?

Comment: yes

`$userid = $_SESSION['uid'];
$lookupusername = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID='$userid'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($lookupusername);
$username = $row['username'];`

Comment: Move your php part on top of the page (before <script>)